# Reading over 254 columns from an Excel 2010 file using ACE SQL server

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I am using the connection string

```
szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & fpath & fname & ";" & _
"Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;"";"

Set rsData = New ADODB.Recordset
'Run the query as adCmdText
rsData.Open szSQL, szConnect, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

'Check if data exists for query
If Not rsData.EOF Then
    rtnArr = rsData.GetRows  'if the recordset contains data populate the array
Else
    dEmp = True 'no data flag true
    ReDim rtnArr(0 To 0, 0 To 0)
End If
```

to run SQL queries in VBA from an external Excel 2010 file. The file has over 40 sheets and each sheet is approx. 369 columns wide, currently the SQL is only returning the first 255 columns of data as per the SQL server limitations. A number of forums discussing this problem suggest transforming the workbook into a flat (.csv) however this wouldn't be ideal. Does anyone have an alterative solution to this? Or a way of forcing through the extra columns?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no SQL Server connection here. Your are connecting to a workbook source. While the ACE/JET engine (used in MS Office/Windows products) does have a 255 column limit, SQL Server does not and if directly connecting to MSSQL via ADO all data should return.

Answer (score -1):

ADO has a limit of 255 fields when connecting to Excel. (see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-specifications-2eedf198-6b27-4dc5-ae07-3e1fba6d6c96) for limitations - ACE/JET/Access are intricately linked)

Your best bet would be to try opening the excel file as an excel file, and reading the cells to create an insert statement

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim OWorkbook As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set OWorkbook = xlApp.workbooks.Open("MyFile.xlsx")

With OWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    c1 = .Cells(RowCount, 1).value
    ...
    c290 = .Cells(RowCount, 290).value
```

Then construct the Insert

```
strInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable] ([Val1],[Val2],...,[Val290])"

strSQLValues = " VALUES (" & c1 & ", '" & c2 & "'," & ... & c290 & ")"
cmd.ActiveConnection = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=MyServer;Database=MyDB"
cmd.CommandText = strInsertSQL & strSQLValues
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
cmd.Execute 'strInsertSQL & strSQLValues
```

Increment `RowCount` as needed

Comment: Thanks but this hasn't worked for me.. perhaps its due to another part of my code? I'll edit the question to include some more detail.

Comment: ADO is an interface and not an SQL engine. OP uses ADO to connect to the ACE/JET Engine (Window .dll files) which Excel/Access and other Window programs can connect to. This SQL engine does have the 255 column limit. But if OP connects directly to SQL Server, Oracle, DB2 still using ADO no such column limit should occur.

Comment: @Parfait, The connection via ADO is being made to Excel, which does suffer the 255 fields limit. I know that ADO to SQL server has a 1024 Field limit, but SQL server is not the data source